# Set width of a fragment view dynamically in android

Tags: android

Following is code:

```
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

How to set this width of this layout as half of the screen ?

Comment: Try getting layout params of the parent, and setting setMargins on the param.

Comment: i want to set that width of the navigation drawer. As per you it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the View of your Fragment be 50% of the screen. Make the width of the container view where you put your Fragment in 50% of the screen.

Comment: i want to set that width of the navigation drawer. As per you it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

First you get the width of the screen:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
try {
    display.getRealSize(size); 
} catch (NoSuchMethodError err) { // Due to some sdk compatibility issue
    display.getSize(size);
}
int width = size.x; // this is your screen width
```

Now, set it to the layout:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            (int)(width/2), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layout_lp);
```

Comment: i want to set that width of the navigation drawer. As per you it's not working.

Comment: what is the result you getting when applying my code?!!